# eclipse template variable order

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

Suppose I have a template pattern like this:

```
System.out.println("${method}"+ ${obj:localVar}.${method} + "${method}");
```

which will prompt

[image]

in the editor.

What I want is something like:
[image]

The problem is: Before hitting enter and complete the template, the template provides a chance for me to edit the somewhat `base` variable which is indicated by that square around it.  But it seems that I'm stuck with the first occurrence of that variable. That is not what I want. I'd like to edit the second one instead. (Because I would like to use some code assistence in the evaluation)

How to specify that in the template pattern?

edit:

It seems that I didn't make my question clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the template is concerned, they are the same value (i.e. all three are the value of the variable `${abc}`, so you can't change only one of the three instances of that value without changing the other two.

Once the template has been evaluated, you can change any part of the resulting expression. It's just code at that point.

```
System.out.println("def" + hello + "def");
```

Comment: I understand what you say, but that's not what I asked. I edited the post. Hopefully it is clearer this time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In your case you can get around this using the String.format() method. Try the following code in your template:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%2$$s%1$$s%2$$s",${obj:localVar}.${method},"${method}"));
```

The format string (the fancy part with all that dollar and percent signs in it) is for reordering the arguments. **${obj:localVar}** evaluates to a local variable in scope. **${method}** is a custom variable in this template. If you want method proposal while filling in the value for it press CTRL+Space again.

I needed this in another case. I think what you want is a debug output containing the method name and its return value. The resulting string for your example above is

```
methodnameRETURNVALUEmethodname
```

In your case I will recommend you to use a logging framework if you need this often!

In case you only need to reorder the arguments, because Eclipse doesn't let you specify the input order, this will be a good starting point.